# change image of header with effects when i hover on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have header image in a div and another div with some content below the header div. when ever I hover the content div the header image should change to another image with some effect. Is this can be done with css itself or jquery is needed?..Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If You need effects while changing we need javascript or jquery for it.

Here i made a simple image change function on animate()

css

```
  #header{ background:url(http://blogs-images.forbes.com/daviddisalvo/files/2012/01/googlelogo2.jpg) no-repeat; width:700px; height:400px;}
```

Html

```
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content">Blah Blah Blah</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#content').mouseover(function(){
 $('#header').animate({ opacity:1});
 $('#header').css('background','url(http://www.google.com/mobile/android/images/android.jpg)')
 $('#header').animate({ opacity:0.1});
 });
 $('#content').mouseleave(function(){
 $('#header').animate({ opacity:0.1});
 $('#header').css('background','url(http://blogs-images.forbes.com/daviddisalvo/files/2012/01/googlelogo2.jpg) no-repeat')
 $('#header').animate({ opacity:1});
});

 });
```

You can check the output [here](http://jsbin.com/ilawuj/1/)

Comment: OP does not want to change the image on hover of the image itself but when the hover is on the text underneath the image.

Comment: Oops i mis-understood the question now its changed :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS won't allow to use the :hover class on another element so you need JavaScript to do this.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEp4z/) No animation

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEp4z/1/) with animation

Javascript

```
$('#content').hover(function() {
    $('.hover-image').fadeIn('slow');
},
function() {
    $('.hover-image').fadeOut('slow');
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/images/header-contest/full/avto.jpg" />
    <img class="hover-image" src="http://mitosoc.org/blogs/wp-content/themes/Cutline2pt1/images/header.jpg">
</div>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum viverra tortor donec nulla torquent porttitor diam praesent viverra, curae felis semper ad ultricies vitae placerat convallis sagittis felis, quisque etiam dui in primis sit curabitur porttitor ornare velit fames aptent lobortis accumsan torquent quam libero fames, porttitor etiam netus suspendisse sagittis potenti.</div>
```

CSS

```
#header { overflow:hidden; width:850px; height:200px; position:relative; }
.hover-image { display:none; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0; left:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.logo-img{
     background-color:green;
}
.logo-img:hover{
     opacity:0.5;
     background-color:red;
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="/img/logo.png" class="logo-img">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked.